# Custom Gutenberg Block Slider

Tags: slider, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am currently trying to wrap my head around the new world of Gutenberg Block development and React components, which is all fairly new territory for me.

So far I have only managed to create a simple block with RichText, using the @wordpress/create-block tool.

However, my goal is to create a Slider Block, which requires me to be able to upload and preferably arrange the order of the images for the slider.

What I have found so far is that the MediaUpload component might head me in the right direction, though I have no clue what to do with this: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/block-editor/src/components/media-upload

Maybe someone can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

For that, you can use [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/image-text-slider-block/). May it's useful to you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. My goal is to learn how to develop blocks myself in order to create my own plugins. Though I will maybe have a look at the source code of this plugin, in case it can show me more about how it is done

Comment: Thanks for your response, yes you can review the code of this plugin. It was completely created by me.